# Possible purpose for a resistor and diode in parallel on a short transmission line to a digital input?

Tags: integrated-circuit, transmission-line, reverse-engineering

During some reverse engineering, I've come across circuits similar to this one shown, where a diode and a rather large resistor (mega-ohms) are in parallel across the source of a signal.

Here, when SW1 is closed, Vout will drop to 0 and the IC will read that as such.

Just curious what the possible purpose of a diode could be here.

My only educated case based on [this article](https://www.arrow.com/en/research-and-events/articles/using-a-protection-diode-to-safeguard-circuits-and-devices) is that the diode could protect the circuit from reverse polarity.

[simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgA3CwqmvKhDxDY0UMTQFiqMBGwBO3AUMG9+YsPHkgMkGsNE69K9fE0ATbXiNCMV-VRQgzDAGYBDAK4AbAC5sA7tq69pZ6ItIBoSF4auFQkTFKVLbWEYEpikGp8enBxvlCkAmxosRCcUWBiZllSfEA5iC1NUI8eFKRzcYaKNlFAM5N5aXKhWLuXv0MncNUPWGiRQAOyL0h85kQaVkhxhVsQA)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgk8QM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diode protects the IC from V1 being connected in reverse. R2 possibly protects V1 itself from over-current in this scenario (or possibly it just represents the internal resistance of V1).

The resistor ensures that even if V1 is removed (for example, if it's powered off, or it's a microcontroller I/O pin that's sometimes (at start-up) set for input mode) there will be a valid logic level at the IC input.

Comment: Diode protection like The Photon described (sometime with an added series resistor to limit the current) is quite common on interfaces that go outside of your own box, or unit, where you may not have as much control over things.